# Alpine Linux can't install lapack-dev on python:3.5-alpine3.4

Tags: installation, alpine-linux, lapack, alpine-package-keeper

I'm using docker `python:3.5-alpine3.4` image and trying to install `lapack-dev` but it keeps failing. It is complaining that it can't find `libgfortran.so.5`. However, I've tried installing libgfortran and that does not seem to fix the problem.

```
(1/1) Installing libgfortran (5.3.0-r0)
OK: 33 MiB in 37 packages
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-8.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-8.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: This apk-tools is OLD! Some packages might not function properly.

ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  so:libgfortran.so.5 (missing):

    required by:
      lapack-3.8.0-r1[so:libgfortran.so.5]
```

Any ideas how I can fix this? Here is the relevant `RUN` step.

```
FROM python:3.5-alpine3.4

RUN echo "http://dl-8.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
  && apk update \
  && apk add --update-cache --no-cache libgcc libquadmath musl \
  && apk add --update-cache --no-cache libgfortran \
  && apk add --update-cache --no-cache lapack-dev
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`python:3.5-alpine3.4` docker image is based on `Alpine v3.4`. [lapack-dev](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.5/community/x86_64/lapack-dev) package was appeared only in `Alpine v3.5`. 
So, my suggestion is to install `lapack-dev` package from the nearest repository by time. In this case you shouldn't face issues with outdated dependencies. 
And it works pretty well.

The final `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM python:3.5-alpine3.4

RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
  && apk update \
  && apk add --update-cache --no-cache libgcc libquadmath musl \
  && apk add --update-cache --no-cache libgfortran \
  && apk add --update-cache --no-cache lapack-dev
```